# Setting device twin properties within azure

Tags: azure-iot-hub

I've been struggling with this for a couple of days. I would like to be able to alter the "desired" properties of a device twin from, say, a function within azure, using the device ID. I was hoping the logic apps would have a simple connection for this, but there is nothing I can find. So I've been playing with trying to ingest an event stream wit a function app. Has anyone found any way to alter twin properties without using API calls or the text editor on the twin page?

Comment: you can use a Device Explorer on the Azure IoT Hub portal or Postman to send a REST Call, see more details https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/iothub/DeviceTwinApi/UpdateDeviceTwin

Comment: Setting device twin desired/tags properties is very straightforward way using a HTTP PATCH call with a SAS Authorization header and the json formatted payload of the patch device twin properties. This HTTP call can be used in the function, logic app, etc.

Comment: I understand that, and it's what I currently do. I was trying to "cut out the middle man" this IS a cloud solution

Comment: There's no way to change twin not using API. Are you trying to get some automation? E.g. setup endpoints, keys, and then just call your own API to pass in a changed desired properties?

Comment: Basically, the device twin desired/tags properties can be setup directly  via an Azure IoT Hub service-facing endpoint (REST API) or using a bulk job, see more details https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-bulk-identity-mgmt. Other option, such as an indirect way to setup a device twin desired/tags properties is via the Azure IoT Hub device-facing endpoint, where the device will update its reported properties and the Azure Function behind the Azure IoT Hub Routes TwinChangeEvents will synchronize this update with desired/tags properties.

Comment: Does it help if you use the IoT Hub Service SDK? The service app in this article (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-csharp-csharp-twin-getstarted#create-the-service-app) uses the RegistryManager class to update the twin. You can do the same thing with the Java and Node SDKs.

Comment: Ok, that's what I'd seen, I was sort of hoping that the device twins would be accessible through the logic apps, or some similar UI interface, for ease of setup. I'm putting together a use case article and trying to make it as simple as possible, little to no actual code, other than the device client setup. The bulk operations are something I was hoping for also though, it looks like building a simple function app that utilizes the API will be the best I can do. Thanks for your help